# How to slice/trim this value?

Tags: c#, .net, stringbuilder

I am trying to remove the last 6 characters from `item.Size` because the data has a decimal place and 5 trailing 0s in the database.

```
sb.Append("<div>" + item.Size + " " + item.Units + "&nbsp;</div>");
```

ie. item.Size is displayed as 1.00000 and I need it to just be displayed as 1.

This is part of a StringBuilder, and as I'm new to coding, not even sure the right way to go about this.

Comment: decimal.Truncate( decimal ) --> truncates 123.456 to 123 for decimals.

Comment: If `Size` is a numeric value then why is it stored in a `string`?

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(item.Size)`

Comment: `Double.Parse(item.Size).ToString("#,##0");` - yes, why is it a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sb.Append("<div>" + (int)item.Size + " " + item.Units + "&nbsp;</div>");
```

Comment: @Jonesopolis 100 points ahead of the data type double or decimal :-)

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` has the same formatting capabilities as `String.Format` when you use the `AppendFormat` method:

```
sb.AppendFormat("<div>{0:N0} {1}&nbsp;</div>", item.Size, item.Units);
```

The format string "N0" tells it to format the number with 0 decimal points. That assumes the item.Size is stored as a numerical type. If not, simply remove the part of the string you don't want:

```
sb.AppendFormat("<div>{0} {1}</div>", item.Size.Split('.')[0], item.Units);
```

Here I've used `Split`, assuming that the value is actually something like what you've shown in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Better you use [int.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)(or `Int32.TryParse`) method. because if `item.Size` is not convertible to `int`, then it wont give you any exception. you can use `int` or `long` according to your choice. So you can handle this in your code according to the if/else condition.

Sample Code:

```
    int size;
    string str = "";
    if(int.TryParse(str, out size) == true)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
```